# How to use Azure SQL Always Encrypted in Azure DevOps CI/CD pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-sql-database, always-encrypted

I’m planning to setup Azure DevOps CI/CD Pipelines for the Azure SQL Always Encrypted database (i.e. Dacpac file)

Requesting can you please let me know the process on how to implement and also available best practices if there is any.

Comment: Perhaps you could edit the post to share some of what you've already tried in your pipeline?

Comment: How is a database even related to your CI/CD pipeline? You really should explain a lot more about your issue.

Comment: I think the OP wants to deploy dacpac files via pipeline. Definitely possible, not even difficult, but OP needs to come up with a lot more info (like what has been done thus far)

Comment: There are articles published on the topic that can answer your questions better than we can here. Try this for starters: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/configure-always-encrypted-using-dacpac?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no official document available for your requirement.

Alternatively, you can go through this third-party tutorial available [here](https://medium.com/@remy.ursem/how-to-use-azure-sql-always-encrypted-in-your-ci-cd-pipeline-cb35b0c64458).

This GitHub repo https://github.com/rebremer/blog-sqldbalwaysencrypted-git will help you to implement your requirement.